# item.getActionView() is returning null

Tags: android, android-actionbar

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_spinner"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.Spinner"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:visible="true"  />
```

```
  public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
      MenuItem mSpinnerItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_spinner);mSpinnerItem.setVisible(true);
      aSpinner = (Spinner) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(mSpinnerItem);
  }
```

By using this...
I am getting menu Item spinner item in to normal View Spinner....
To set the Adapter i did like this...
But while doing this the spinner item is getting null reference...
Please help me how to escape from this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you should populate a spinner.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html

But this is how you should do it via code.

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
// Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a   default spinner layout
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter =      ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
    R.array.planets_array,       android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
// Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
// Apply the adapter to the spinner
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

EDIT: Here is the code for the ActionBar spinner.

```
    import android.app.ActionBar;
    import android.app.Fragment;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.view.Gravity;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    ActionBar.OnNavigationListener {


    /**
   * The serialization (saved instance state) Bundle key representing the
   * current dropdown position.
   */

  private static final String STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM = "selected_navigation_item";

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Set up the action bar to show a dropdown list.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

    final String[] dropdownValues = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.dropdown);

    // Specify a SpinnerAdapter to populate the dropdown list.
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(actionBar.getThemedContext(),
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, android.R.id.text1,
        dropdownValues);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // Set up the dropdown list navigation in the action bar.
    actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, this);

    // use getActionBar().getThemedContext() to ensure
    // that the text color is always appropriate for the action bar
    // background rather than the activity background.
  }

  @Override
  public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Restore the previously serialized current dropdown position.
    if (savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM)) {
      getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM));
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // Serialize the current dropdown position.
    outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM, getActionBar()
        .getSelectedNavigationIndex());
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int position, long id) {
    // When the given dropdown item is selected, show its contents in the
    // container view.
    Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
    return true;
  }


/**
   * A dummy fragment
   */

  public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "placeholder_text";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
      textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
      textView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
      return textView;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: This is works for spinner..But not for Actionbar Spinner or navigationList

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html scroll down to Example SpinnerAdapter and OnNavigationListener. Should be good to go :)

Comment: Thanks... can you tell me how to access that Spinner into Spinner class